# Trying to calculate UTP and LTP of opamp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, schmitt-trigger

I'm doing a practise test and one of the questions is asking me to find the upper trip point (UTP) and lower trip point (LTP) of the following circuit:

[image: Circuit given in question]

I'm not sure how to do it with a circuit of this configuration.
Could anybody tell me how I should go about it?

Comment: Rather than edit the title to say solved they'll be a tick next to Dave's answer you can click to accept the answer. That marks the question has solved / answered and also awards a bonus to the person that answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trigger points occur when the two input terminals of the opamp have the same voltage. There are two cases, one with the output high and one with the output low. For each case, find the input voltage that makes the two inputs to the opamp equal.

Answer (score 4):

In general, I agree with answer above addressing UTP and LTP.

But there's a specific problem with \$\pm 3.3\$ Volt rails for the op-amp when considering the 12 Volts applied to the inverting input's voltage divider.

The inverting input will sit at $$12\text{V} \times \left(\frac{6.8\text{k}\Omega}{2.2\text{k}\Omega + 6.8\text{k}\Omega}\right)\approx  +9.07V$$

That's higher than the +3.3 V rail of the op-amp.  You shouldn't do that in the real world, the magic smoke might escape.

Answer (score -1):

to calculate utp v(in)+((- vin+ vsat)*3.9)/(3.9+6.8)
for ltp replace vsat with -vsat

Comment: I would be happy to upvote if you explained how you derived your formula.